# Comparing two large files having different order using Unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix, informatica-powercenter

I have two text files each of size 3.5GB that I want to compare using Unix script. The files contain around 5 million records in them.

The layout of the files are like below.

```
*<sysdate>
<Agent Name 1>
<Agent Address 1>
<Agent Address 2>
<Agent Address 3>
...
<Agent Name 2>
<Agent Address 1>
<Agent Address 2>
<Agent Address 3>
...
<Total number of records present>*
```

Sample file.

```
<sysdate>
Sachin Tendulkar    11051973    M
AddrID1     AddrLn11        AddrLn12        City1   State1  Country1    Phn1    OffcAddr11  OffcAddr12  St1 Cntry1
AddrID2     AddrLn21        AddrLn22        City2   State2  Country2    Phn2    OffcAddr21  OffcAddr22  St2 Cntry2
...
Sourav Ganguly  04221975    M
AddrID1     AddrLn11        AddrLn12        City1   State1  Country1    Phn1    OffcAddr11  OffcAddr12  St1 Cntry1
AddrID2     AddrLn21        AddrLn22        City2   State2  Country2    Phn2    OffcAddr21  OffcAddr22  St2 Cntry2
...
<Total number of records present>
```

The order of the Agent addresses in the two files is different. I need to find the records that are present in one file but not in the other and also the mismatched records. I tried sorting the files using Unix sort command initially but it failed due to server space issue. ETL (Informatica) approach can also be considered.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please, post a sample of both files with the expected output which clearly shows when there is a match or a miss, ie. do you just need the agent names which are present/not present or do differing addresses dictate that or what.

Comment: Sample file added.
One is the good file and the other is the erroneous file.

The Agents will appear in the same order in both the files but the order of the addresses inside each of these Agents are different.

Cases of mismatches:
1. First file may have a few more Agents than the second file.
2. First file may have a few more addresses present inside a single Agent. May have duplicate address IDs as well.
3. Same address ID may bear different Address lines in both the files.

I need make both the files exactly same by removing all the mismatches occurring in the erroneous file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` and start writing to a new file each time you match `Agent Name` and give that file the name of the agent (perkaps in subdir's using the first three characters). Next compare the directories (trees) from both input files (`diff -r`).
Another solution is importing all records in two different tables and use sql to compare:

```
select name from table1 where name not in (select name from table2);
select name from table2 where name not in (select name from table1);
select name from table1 
inner join table2 on table1.name=table2.name
where table1.address1 <> table2.address1
   or table1.address2 <> table2.address2
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In informatica load both the files.

find MD5 of each row, by concatenating each column, For example:
MD5(COL1||Col2||COL3)

Now compare both the MD5 values from each file by using joiner, by this way you can find matching and non-matching rows.

Answer (score 0):

first at all, send an example of the 2nd file

why you cant sorter the data with the sorter transformation?

my approuch would be concatenate the first 3 columns (name,addres1,addres2) and make it as key, next use a joiner transformation to match the data.

you also can do a union transformation and after that an aggregator transformation to count how many times the key that you create is found
if the count is equal to 2, mean that the data is in both files
if the count is equal to 1, mean that the data is in just 1 file

send more info about the problem to be more specific

Answer (score 0):

Try to restructure your data first.

Keep adding the AgentName and other fields to every address related to that agent. Use simple tricky expression logic, like a variable/counting methodology to achieve this. By doing this your flat files will be compare-friendly & can be compared easily either in UNIX or in Informatica.

Let me know if you are interested in this solution, shall help you more.